# installing mysql db on os x 10.10.1 yosemite

Tags: mysql-python

I see many threads on problems installing mysql db on mac but they're mostly older discussions. Has anyone found an easy way to get up a running with mysql db on mac's os x 10.10.1 yosemite? I've got the mysql dmg file installed (from mysql.com) but that's as far as I've gotten.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: copy and paste this into Terminal (but be sure to read more first):

```
bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)
```

This will install and configure everything automagically. The script is provided by MacMiniVault and is available on [Github](https://github.com/MacMiniVault/Mac-Scripts). More information about the mySQL install script on http://www.macminivault.com/mysql-yosemite/.